# insert or update if exists databse (with wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-insert

I need to insert the data from wordpress to database...but right now with this code i only can insert new values to the database (gerating duplicates)

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->replace(bruno_wallet, array( 
      'foto' => $ii,
      'data' => $data ,
      'nome' => $nome[0],
      'evento' => $evento ,
      'horarios' => $horarios,
      'obs' => $obs,
      'horas' => $numeros_horas,
      'valorhora' => $valor_horas ,
      'totalparcial' => $total_parcial,
      'props' => $props,
      'id_do_mes' => $id_postt,
      'nome_id' => $nomeid
    ));
```

Comment: @MikelBitson - in databases, you never query to check if something exists in order to insert or update. That's prone to concurrency, you can end up with duplicates (which you don't want). We use `unique` constraint with `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ` syntax - that's a 1 liner, and you can never get duplicates that way, no matter how many users are accessing MySQL at the same time.

Comment: How can you write me the php insert command?

Comment: No, but if you try it, we can help if you get stuck...

Comment: i tryed this : INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
foto='$ii', data='$data', nome='$evento', horarios='$horarios', obs='$obs', horas='$numeros_horas', valorhora='$valor_horas', totalparcial='$total_parcial', props='$props',  id_do_mes='$id_postt',  nome_id='$nomeid'

Comment: but some sintax error ? php dont run

Comment: You need to post that syntax error, or read it and try to fix the issues. We can't help you with "some sintax error" because it doesn't give us enough information.

Comment: thats the error..im using php ...  i get sintax error ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: ok i get it : $sqlx="INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid') " ;
$result=mysql_query($sqlx);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me :

```
$sqlx="INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid') " ; $result=mysql_query($sqlx);
```